# How to get profile URL from linkedIn API V2?

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, spring-social-linkedin

How can i get profile URL from linkedIn API V2 (api.linkedin.com/v2)?
**Requested &scope=r_emailaddress%20r_liteprofile**
response have only firstname,lastname,id and profile_picture 
before v2 we were able to find out profile URL from id (example:
**https://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=$ID** )
but now this shows profile not found error and doesn't work.
i have gone through many links and read LinkedIn documentation but didn't find the right solution moreover i have read on stackoverflow linkedIn don't recommend r_fullprofile permission just for vanity name is this correct ?
what should i do to get profile URl from linkedin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't with the `scope` you mentioned.

You need to add `r_basicprofile` to the scope to request the `vanityName`.

A few considerations:

- Your app needs to have the permission `r_basicprofile` available, you can check that by going [here](https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps), then select your app, then go to the "Auth" tab, and after check the "Permissions" section.
- You need to add `r_basicprofile` to the `scope` query param
- [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api?context=linkedin/marketing/context#request) you can see that you are able to fetch the `vanityName` property, then all you need to do is concatenate with `https://www.linkedin.com/in/` to have the full profile URL as in "https://www.linkedin.com/in/ + vanityName"
- Linkedin doesn't give `r_basicprofile` permissions to any app, you need to request it to LinkedIn and they might not give it to you.

Comment: @AnujKumar You need to add to the query param
`scope=r_emailaddress%20r_basicprofile` instead of `scope=r_emailaddress%20r_liteprofile` the thing is that your application needs to have permission from linkedin to request that scope, check it on developers.linkedin.com to see if it has that permission.

Comment: thanks for your response. Actually we don't have the r_basicprofile access. I was in touch with their support to get that access. Turns out that in the recent release of their API, they changed the permission structure and now this access is given only to a specific use case on a request approval basis.

Comment: @AnujKumar I updated my response to cover that too, the last bullet point in the considerations.